# Macro is trying to connect to deleted copy of the file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button that is supposed to update all pivot tables in the sheet that the button is located, this is the code that I made

```
Sub Update_Pivot()

Dim pCache As PivotCache

For Each pCache In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
pCache.Refresh
Next pCache

End Sub
```

So yesterday, when I tried to use this button I obtained the following error message

```
Run-time error'1004':

Can't open PivotTable source file
"Here goes the path for a personal folder that I have that is not where this Excel file is located"
```

Because I saw that the macro was pointing at my personal folder, and I realised that I have a copy of this file there I decided to delete the copy, the problem is that now when I use this macro I get this other error message

```
Sorry, we couldn't find "File that I deleted earlier from my personal folder" is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?
```

My question is, why is my macro trying to connect to a deleted copy of the file? Nowhere in the code I'm telling it to do something like that. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Your macro does not try to connect anywhere... Your macro tries to refresh `PivotCaches`, which have connections defined according to the workbook  path, when they have been created. If you know where this path is, you should put back the appropriate workbook there. If not, you should create another one.

Comment: @FaneDuru How can I find this path? also, what do you mean by "create another one"?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this to see the sources

```vb
Sub ShowSources()

    Dim pcache As PivotCache, msg As String
    For Each pcache In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
       msg = msg & vbCrLf & pcache.Index & ") " & pcache.SourceData
    Next pcache
    MsgBox msg

End Sub
```